# How do i restore from snapshot by softlayer api?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Using softlayer api and slcli utility,i try to restore volume from snapshot.
But i can't restore from softlayer api with python and from slcli.

How do i restore from snapthot by softlayer api with python?

### used my command

volumeid:13010889  snapshotid:13230363

#### slcli

slcli snapshot restore-volume 13230363 13010889

#### python

import SoftLayer

client = SoftLayer.Client()

iscsi = client['Network_Storage_Iscsi']

iscsi.restoreFromSnapshot(13230371,id=13010889)

Comment: i can restore volume by custemer portal

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice that you paste the error you got, anyway your code is fine what I think is wrong is the data you are sending:

1. You need to make sure that the id of the network storage you are using is the correct and that its status is active (This is for the case when you have replicas), in case it is inactive the method will fail, in order the method woks you need to use the id of the active volume (Primary or Replica).
2. Make sure that the snapshot id is the correct you need to use this method [getSnapshotsForVolume](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi/getSnapshotsForVolume) and again in order to get the corect list you need to use the ID of the Active storage (Primary or Replica)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the [restoreFromSnapshot](https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi/restoreFromSnapshot) API call is indeed broken. I have left confidential information blank.

```
/home/scripts > ./snapshot.py list 12193217
VOLUM ID: 12193217
+---+-------------------+----------+----------+---------------------------+
| # |      username     |    id    | nasType  |         createDate        |
+---+-------------------+----------+----------+---------------------------+
| 7 |       ***         | 13020991 | SNAPSHOT |  ***                      |


 /home/scripts > ./snapshot.py restore 12193217 13020991
 iscsi id: 12193217
 iscsi snapshot ID: 13020991
 True


    def restore_from_snapshot(sl_config, volume_id, snapshot_id):
        """ Restore drive from specified snapshot """
        if snapshot_id and volume_id: 
            volume_id = volume_id[0]
            snapshot_id = snapshot_id[0]
            #print "snapshot_id = %s :: volume_id = %s" % snapshot_id % volume_id
            iscsi_mgr = SoftLayer.ISCSIManager(SL.instance(sl_config).client)
            iscsi_id = helpers.resolve_id(iscsi_mgr.resolve_ids, volume_id,'iSCSI')
            print "iscsi id: %i" % iscsi_id
            iscsi_snapshot_id = helpers.resolve_id(iscsi_mgr.resolve_ids, snapshot_id,'Snapshot')
            print "iscsi snapshot ID: %i " % iscsi_snapshot_id
            iscsi = SL.instance(sl_config).client['Network_Storage_Iscsi']
            snapshot_output = iscsi.restoreFromSnapshot(iscsi_snapshot_id, id=iscsi_id)

            print snapshot_output
```

After this Nothing happens. Only through the Web API does the restore work. SLCLI is also broken(it uses this same service).

Comment: try using the http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/restoreFromSnapshot method, It seems that http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi/restoreFromSnapshot has a different way because long ago the ISCSI devices were diferent than the current. and the implementation to restore snapshots may be different.